# MSB1009 : Project file does not exist

Tags: web3js, truffle, ipfs

I am trying to install Web3 js. It gives me error of MSBUILD. I am not able to proceed further.

I have tried installing new version of node.js. But still i am not able to install Web3 js successful.

```
npm install web3

C:\Windows\System32>npm install web3
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt\build\..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: build/binding.sln
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm WARN prop-types-extra@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.4 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.4 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-prop-types@0.4.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.3 requires a peer of react-dom@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uncontrollable@5.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN System32 No description
npm WARN System32 No repository field.
npm WARN System32 No README data
npm WARN System32 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I executed "node-gyp configure" in cmd and saw that Python was not found. So I installed Python 2.7 
After installing python the error was gone.